# How to read contacts - react native

Tags: react-native

I want to read all contacts. I'm using this library:

https://github.com/rt2zz/react-native-contacts

I installed it and I added this permission on manifest.xml :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
```

but when I want to call getAll function my app is show me `Unfortunately, *** has stopped`

```
 componentDidMount(){
   Contacts.getAll((err, contacts) => {
  if (err) throw  err

    //console.log(contacts)
  })
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

New versions of android need explicit user permissions apart from the manifest.xml

```
PermissionsAndroid.request(PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.READ_CONTACTS, {
      title: "Contacts",
      message: "This app would like to view your contacts."
    }).then(() => {
      Contacts.getAll((err, contacts) => {
        if (err === "denied") {
          // error
        } else {
          console.log(contacts[0]);
        }
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Install the library, am using npm for this example:

`npm install react-native-contacts`

Add the read contact permission to your `AndroidManifest.xml`

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />`

This is the basic code example.

```
import Contacts from 'react-native-contacts';

Contacts.getAll((err, contacts) => {
  if (err) throw err;

  // contacts returned
  console.log(contacts)
})
```

Ensure that you are actually doing the  `import`.

Answer (score 0):

Install package with npm

`npm install react-native-contacts`

Install package with yarn

`yarn add react-native-contacts`

and then do

`react-native link react-native-contacts`

Add the read contact permission to your AndroidManifest.xml

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />`

simple code

```
import Contacts from 'react-native-contacts';
componentDidMount(){
 Contacts.getAll((err, contacts) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  // contacts returned
  console.log(contacts)
})
}
```

then

1 - You must rebuild your application

2 - Then go to the application settings and give permission to the contacts

3 - react-native run-android

Answer (score 0):

you need request Premissions for users.

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/permissionsandroid.html

```
async requestReadContactsPermission() {
    try {
      const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
        PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.READ_CONTACTS,
        {
          'title': 'App Premission',
          'message': 'Chat x App need permission.'
        }
      )
      if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
        console.log("You can read contacts")
      } else {
        console.log("read contacts permission denied")
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.warn(err)
    }
  }
```

Then you need to check if the permissions are authorized

```
listContacts() {
    this.requestReadContactsPermission().then(
        Contacts.checkPermission((err, permission) => {
            if (err) throw err;

            // Contacts.PERMISSION_AUTHORIZED || Contacts.PERMISSION_UNDEFINED || Contacts.PERMISSION_DENIED
            if (permission === 'undefined') {
              Contacts.requestPermission((err, permission) => {
                // ...
              })
            }
            if (permission === 'authorized') {
              this.getAllContacts()
            }
            if (permission === 'denied') {
              // x.x
            }
          })
    )

}
```

After this you can read the contact list

```
    Contacts.getAll((err, contacts) => {
      if (err) throw err;

          // contacts returned
         console.log(contacts)
      })
```